# GRE percentage problem (Tricky)

Tags: percentages, gre-exam

[image]

The number of television sets sold by Store R last month was approximately what percent less than the number of television sets sold by Store T last month?

The answer is 56 percent, which I have no idea how it's solved. I just get 25 percent by finding the percentage change from $40$ to $50$. Not sure how the answer is 56 percent. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the number of units of products sold by the stores is given in the second graph, we should not look at the data from the first and proceed the calculation.

Note that the number of units sold **are expressed as a percentage of number of units in stock, based on data from the first graph.**

Number of units sold by store $R = 50$% of units in stock$_{R} = \frac {1}{2}\times 40 =20$

Number of units sold by store $T = 90$% of units in stock $_{T} = \frac {9}{10}\times 50 =45$

Now, $$\text {percentage change} = \frac {45-20}{45} \times 100 $$ $$= \frac {5}{9} \times 100 = 55.55 \text {  percent  } \approx 56 \text {  percent  } $$

Hope it helps.